# Rails based S3 file manager

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, open-source, amazon-s3

I'm looking for an open source project that provides a file manager type interface to S3.  The ability to view files and "folders", add/edit/delete files/folders, etc.

I've seen http://s3fm.com, but I'd like to host something like that myself.  Does anything like this exist?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend a 2 part solution:

1. Use [S3FS](http://shahidz.com/mounting-amazon-s3-bucket-to-a-local-linux-file-system/) to mount a remote S3 bucket to the local linux filesystem on your server.
2. Once that's mounted you can use a general file management tool like [Boxroom](http://boxroom.rubyforge.org/) or the [jQuery FileTree Connector](http://www.dnamique.com/file-browser-for-ruby-on-rails/)

Something to note, I've also seen much better performance over the volume mounted S3 shares than trying to access through my own API calls using something like [S3Ruby](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I hadn't thought of or heard of something like s3fs.  How would I manage multiple users creating multiple folders/files with s3fs?  Do I actually create the the folders/files on the filesytem, and let a filemanager script manage it?  Or do I just create a single folder, dump all the files in it and use a "virtual" filesystem like BoxRoom does?  If you've done this before, I'd love to get your thoughts.  Thanks.

Comment: I use s3fs extensively in production (typically for backups). As to how to proceed I don't really know without more knowledge of what you are trying to accomplish with your application. In general, I'd favor segmenting things at a higher level (per user folders) if for no other reason than I think it would help your sanity debugging things.

Comment: Thanks.  Basically I'm creating a multi-user CMS type application with Rails.  So, I'd like to give users the ability to upload and manage files.  I'd like to allow them to store their files in a folder structure of their choosing.  So, if I use s3fs, then I assume I'd need to create actual folders on the filesystem correct?  Then, behind the scenes s3fs would upload to s3?  I'd also have to ensure only user's can see files/folders in their own account.

Answer (score 1):

You can download and install S3fox for mozilla firefox. Look for tutorial videos on how to use it. Its really easy.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using Paperclip would be the most straightforward solution for a CMS.

http://dev.thoughtbot.com/paperclip/classes/Paperclip/Storage/S3.html

Answer (score 0):

Virtual File System does exactly that - it provides simple and unified interface over Local File System, AWS S3, SFTP

Overview: http://alexeypetrushin.github.com/vfs

S3 samples: http://alexeypetrushin.github.com/vfs/s3_basics.html